# How to archive each file in a folder separately?

Tags: compression, archive, 7zip, archiving

I have many files in a folder. If I have a single file, `7z a -t7z archive1.zip -mx0` works fine. But my files are file1, file2 ... I want to archive these files separately like archive1.zip, archive2.zip ...

Note: File names are random and archive names don't necessarily be regular like archive2, archive3. All I want archive names must be parallel to file names. For example screenshot.jpg > screenshot.zip, book.pdf > book.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is using find :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c '7z a -t7z "${1%.*}.zip" -mx0 {}' sh {} \;
```

`-maxdepth 1` is used to not enter subdirectories
`-not -name "*.zip"` is used to exclude archives
`-exec sh -c '' sh {}` is there just to be able to strip the extension from the filename
`"${1%.*}.zip"` transforms filename.extension into filename.zip

Comment: I get an error that `File not found - "${1%.*}.zip`

Comment: Can you post the command you inputed and the whole output ?

Comment: I inputed exactly the same code you write, on my folder. Then command line says,  'File not found - "${1%.*}.zip"'  Also you can see ss. https://i.imgur.com/Z1jRjra.png

By the way,  i took care of it with Winrar Gui. But i would like to do it with CLI.